# Sending and receiving data packets over the internet

Tags: android, python, visual-c++-2015

**What i m trying to do :**
Send a video frame of my android device over Internet to my laptop(windows 10) to receive some json data
**What I did**
1 . Went [here](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/) to learn to create a server to send and receive html requests
2 . Turned off my firewall
**Problem**
I want to send and receive data **over internet** but this allows communication  **only with a LAN**. I didn't try port-forwarding (don't know ho to, if I use hot-spot of my mobile) but what I want to know if I run Skype/counter strike and all, they don't require us to do port forwarding to send and receive data with a peer to peer connection. Neither a web-browser uses the same to do a video chat. 
**Question**
How can I make a windows app with c++ or python to receive a Video frame, do the processing (or make a button to do the same) and send a json coded instruction to android.

**Note :** Getting data over an external server is not what I want here, In short I want to create a skype like app

Answer (score 0):

All that you wanted to is sending a data from your android phone to your server in your computer, then use any tunneling service like [ngrok](http://ngrok.com/).ngrok supports both tcp & http.

```
# http 
  ngrok http <port>
```

Comment: I do not want to use third party server. But I want to learn from the basics how can I send packets from one computer to another like p2p connection by making a server app.